# Laravel Routes: Missing argument 1 for {closure}() / Undefined variable: id

Tags: php, variables, laravel-3

I'm implementing edition of post in my app. I came with this code:

```
Route::get('editpost', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function($id){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $view_post = Post::with('user')->find($id);

    return View::make('admin.editpost')
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('post', $view_post);
}));
```

And later I use the PUT route.

But when I try to edit testing post, I came up with Missing argument 1 for {closure}(). With a little search on Google I didn't seem to find solution. Deleted "$id" in function, and.. "Undefined variable".

Do you mind what cause a problem? Is that code correct?

```
Route::get('editpost', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $view_post = Post::with('user')->find($id);

    return View::make('admin.editpost')
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('post', $view_post);}));

Route::put('post/(:num)', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function($id) {
    $edit_post = array(
        'post_title'  => Input::get('post_title'),
        'post_body'   => Input::get('post_body'),
        'post_author' => Input::get('post_author')
    );

    $rules = array(
        'post_title'  => 'required|min:3|max:255',
        'post_body'   => 'required|min:10'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($edit_post, $rules);
    if ($validation -> fails()){
        return Redirect::to('editpost')
            ->with('user',Auth::user())
            ->with_errors($validation)
            ->with_input();
    }

    $post = Post::with('user')->find($id);
    $post->post_title = $post_title;
    $post->post_body = $post_body;
    $post->post_author = $post_author;
    $post->save();


    //go to all post
    return Redirect::to('news')->with('success_message', true);}));
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to accomplish and I'm not familiar with L3 but typically you need to include `method='PUT'` in your form tag to tell Laravel that it's actually a PUT route. If your issue has nothing to do with this, then disregard. Also you should typically include all your login in a controller. This is clunking up your routes file.

Comment: It's just snippet from my routes.php file. I have actually working login/register and adding post forms. Now, in need is making post editable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with L3, but I think you can do/verify that:

### Fix your edit route

You forget the `(:num)` and the `$id` in `function($id)`:

```
Route::get('editpost/(:num)', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function($id){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $view_post = Post::with('user')->find($id);

    return View::make('admin.editpost')
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('post', $view_post);}));
```

### Check your Form

```
echo Form::open("post/{$post->id}", 'PUT');
```

Comment: I did it, but now laravel keep saying 404.

Comment: 404 because this register/item not exist. For check that, do a select in your database for this `$id`.

Comment: @user3235936 just for test. Verify your URL, check the parameter in route (try execute `echo $id; exit;`).. and check this register in database.